# Absolute position ignored for form elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use absolute positioning for an input element.  Gecko/Blink appear to be ignoring the "right" style (which should force the width), and are instead applying the default width to the element.  This does not happen with other elements like div or span.

I know I can workaround the issue by adding additional containers which can be properly positioned, but I shouldn't have to change the markup to use CSS.  As far as I can tell from the spec, this is a bug, but several browsers appear to be in tacit agreement that this is a good bug to have.

What am I misunderstanding about the spec?  How do I address this in CSS?

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .container > * {
        background-color: #FAA;
        bottom: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 250px;
        top: 5px;
    }
</style>

<!-- this works -->
<div class="container">
    <div>Foo</div>
</div>

<!-- this does not -->
<div class="container">
    <button>Foo</button>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6o3jajr/4/

Notice how the div and span resize with the container, but the input and button do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it behaves differently on some elements, however you could solve this by replacing `right: 250px;` with `width: calc(100% - 250px);`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6o3jajr/5/)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the behavior is according to the CSS 2.1 specs.

`input` elements are replacement elements as their visual is defined by the browser/system and have a intrinsic dimension as of that. According to [10.3.8 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width):
The first rule says `[...]The used value of 'width' is determined as for inline replaced elements.[...]If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the element also has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the used value of 'width'.[...]`
If we then take the last rule into account `[...]If at this point the values are over-constrained[...]` as it would be to large because of the right value `[...]ignore the value for either 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.`.

I might be wrong about it, but reading it that way the behavior would be right.

**EDIT**
I did some search in the issue tracker of FireFox and Chrome and it seems that my reading is correct:

**Bugzilla@Mozilla:**
[Bug 416634 - Inputs no longer stretched by "position:absolute; left:#; right:#" style](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416634):

**Chromium:**
[Issue 281380: Inputs do not follow the rules for replaced absolutely positioned elements correctly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=281380)
[Issue 24360004: Use shrink-to-fit for width for Button, input, select, textarea, and legend treat width value ...](https://codereview.chromium.org/24360004)

Comment: I think you may be correct.  The spec must be wrong then, 'cause that's dumb. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tryed your script... button seems to work. However...

Try this in css...

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.container > * {
    background-color: #FAA;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 250px;
    top: 5px;

    /* This is important to give a maximum width
       to all elements inside container */
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
}

/* Remove border from input box to be perfectly aligned
   to other elements */

input{
    border:0;
}
```

...and this in html

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span>Foo</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input value="Foo" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <button>Foo</button>
</div>
```

> Input dialog works differently from others elements. It have a different minimum size, so if you don't specify `width` it appers short than others.
>   So set in `.container > *` class `width:100%;` and `max-width:500px;`.
>   So you are sure that all elements in `<div class="container">` have the same size. For input box type i suggest to remove border to perfectly align with the other elements.
>
> Note: You can choose any px value for `max-width`, as you wish.

Woking demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yeti82/x0zb4njo/